# datetime format in URL

Tags: datetime, blazor

I have **input** tag(InputDate) in EditForm in Blazor file.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Check In Date</label>
      <InputDate @bind-Value="HomeModel.StartDate" class="form-control" min="@DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")" type="text"/>
</div>
```

then submit this to api server.

But problem is DateTime format with Url, it shows

```
https://localhost:44320/api/hotelroom?checkInDate=04.%2012.%202022&checkOutDate=04.%2013.%202022
```

So the return value is 400 error.

When I check this datetime format with swagger, nothing problem.

StartDate is checkInDate in Url.

when I try to debug, checkInDate shows like '04. 11. 2022'.

I expect this as 04/11/2022.

My pc is set for Japan. Without changing local pc's time setting, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#:~:text=For%20example%2C%20the%20%22d%22,yyyy%2FMM%2Fdd%22.) on date format strings.  When you create the date for the URL you will need to either  use  an invariant culture or else set the format to a specific culture.  Scroll down the documentation to the section "How standard format strings work" to see how it is  done. Docs also in [Japanese](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) if that would be easier.

Comment: You could pass the value as ticks..

Comment: You could also use Epoch and convert to/from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I used 'ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")' method to trans parameter as string, the url always was like this

```
04.%2012.%202022
```

So I used provider

```
ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"))
```

Then everything is good.
string format can't surpass OS system setting.

Thank you all guys replied to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution it's changing the culture of the project when you run it, so in your startup class you should add:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-US" };
    options.AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
        .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures)
        .SetDefaultCulture("en-US");
});
```

Using provider like

```
ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"))
```

Will force you to set every ToString with the new culture info (which can be tedious on a large scale)